# Single sign on - is this a secure way to log in?

Tags: authentication, sso

I am fiddling about with a sort of single sign on procedure.
Let's say there is site1 and site2 and both use an SSL certificate. 
Users are signed in on site1.
I was wondering what the experts think of this way to let users automatically sign in on site2 that is hosted on a different server:

1. clicking on a link in site1 gets the url (on site2) and 2 codes from a database
2. site1 redirects to the url (on site2) and sends the 2 codes as a post request
3. Site2 checks if the page that is redirected from is really from site1 and if the combination of the codes are correct
4. If so site2 creates a hash and stores it in the database and sends the result back to site1
5. Site1 redirects to site2 and sends the hash
6. if the hash is in the database and was received from site1 and within a short time after creating it the user is logged in.

Is this a (fairly) secure way for a signle sign on procedure or is this horribly insecure? If the latter: where do the dangers lie?

Comment: First of all, I hope you agree that home-made protocols may only be used for learning and *never* in production. So even if we told you that we see no errors, that would **not** mean you can use this on actual users. Regarding your idea: The description is very vague and obscure. Why two codes? How does site 2 check that “the combination of the codes is correct”? What does that even mean? What's the hash part supposed to do? Hash of what? I think this needs a lot more work if you want proper answers.

Comment: You should look at OAuth and OpenID. They provide single log in AND have already been tested.

Comment: @Fleche: the 2 codes serve as a check so that no other site could try to access site2, they would have to know these codes (a bit like login/pw combination). the codes are known by site2, they can be stored in a file or db.
The hash contains the actual login: it only remains valid for a short time so it should not be possible to crack it. I said 'hash' but probably 'nonce' would be a better name.
@Gudradain": where would the fun in that be?

Comment: @Fleche: maybe also add: this system is set up so that users could never see the url's that are used to log in, everything is done in the background, so it would be extremely hard (?) to figure out which url's to target

Comment: @bolvo How are they, the 2 codes, known to site2 if it's site1 that generate them? Are they always the same? What protects you against replay attack if that's the case?

Comment: @Gudradain: they are fixed codes. The reply (nonce) is always different and us the actual login. It remains only valid for a short time. Once the reply is used to log in it gets inactivated. All background communication goes from server to server without sending anything back to the user's PC.

Comment: @bolvo At what step is that nonce generated? How does site1 and site2 both know about that nonce? How do you verify identity of both site1 and site2?

Comment: @bolvo Also, if all communication goes from server to server without sending anything back to the user's PC, how do you authenticate that user? You need information provided from the user on his computer AND information stored on the user computer to correctly identify him.

Comment: @Gudradain: The nonce is generated by site2 when site1 posts the 2 codes and then returned to site1. Site1 than redirects to a page and posts the nonce so that it is consumed. The user obviously would need to log in on site1. It is at that point that site2 starts a session with a session variable that grants access to the site

Answer (score 1):

You simply state "site 2 checks if the page that is redirected from is really site 1"... how?  There isn't a good way to do this without further information that site 1 can use to verify it's identity via a challenge from Site 2.

This also seems overly complex for passing an authentication.  All that really needs to be done, as long as Site 1 and Site 2 both communicate with each other and know each other, is for them to agree between themselves on a token and redirect the user with that token so that one site knows it is the same user that was on the other site.

Don't roll your own, use OAuth or something similar, it will allow better integration with more sites and is also a well supported and tested standard.

Comment: I am not sure we are on the same page. Which password is given to a third party?

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread your post.  I'll update my answer momentarily.